# Setting Fragment arguments from Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, race-condition

I'm wondering if calling `setArguments` on a Fragment immediately after its instantiation creates any problems.

For example, say we have the following snippet:

```
Fragment myFragment = new CustomFragment();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putBoolean("amIAnArg", true);
myFragment.setArguments(args);
```

This code seems to work fine, although it looks like the code *should* create a race condition since a Fragment's arguments can only be set before the `onAttach` method is called.

Are there any issues with setting a Fragment's arguments in this way?

Comment: @codeMagic yes that is a typo. Thanks!

Comment: this is exactly how you set arguments because the fragment is created when you commit it to the transaction, not when to create an instance of it

Comment: It's not really a race condition since onAttach() isn't called until you...well, attach the fragment to the Activity (initiate transaction, call show() or replace() etc.). At least to my understanding

Comment: This works just fine. I do this all the time, usually in a `static` getInstance()` method.

Comment: @PseudoProgrammer : How else would it be possible to call `setArguments(...)`? You have to have an instance of any `Object` before you can call its methods.

Comment: @tyczj thank you for your comments! It makes sense that the Fragment lifecycle does not begin until we commit the transaction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just like an `Activity`, `Fragments` have a specific lifecycle, and are not "created" like simple Java objects. When you commit a `FragmentTransaction`, it's asynchronous and isn't immediately attached or created. It's queued on the main thread to occur at a later time. Only then will it go through its lifecycle methods (e.g. `onCreate()`, `onAttach()`).

You *should* set the arguments this way, and should do so before committing the `FragmentTransaction` -- however, you could technically do it right after committing the transaction with no ill effects. As others have stated, what you're doing is the suggested `newInstance()` factory method for fragments [1]. For example:

```
private static final String ARG_IS_ARG = "is_arg";

public static CustomFragment newInstance(boolean isArg) {
    CustomFragment result = new CustomFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putBoolean(ARG_IS_ARG, isArg);
    result.setArguments(args);
    return result;
}
```

[1] http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html

Comment: Calling `setArguments()` in a `newInstance()` factory method is also the way in which I typically set a fragment's arguments. The docs threw me off stating that `setArguments()` "can only be called before the fragment has been attached to its activity; that is, you should call it immediately after constructing the fragment." What I did not take into account was that even after creating the Fragment, we still have to a commit a transaction before the Fragment is attached to the Activity. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There should be no problem.  I am working on a project right now that uses this exact format in several spots.

This format is in the Android Developers example project as well (find 'Arguments'):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what @kcoppock said, in most cases you will be instantiating the `Fragment` on the UI thread, and then Android queues up the arguments you pass to the `Fragment` on the UI thread as well. There's no race conditions because the operations take place at different times on the same thread.

For more information, check out this blog post on Activities and Fragments: http://www.zerotohired.com/2015/02/passing-data-between-activities-and-fragments-in-android.