# Android fragment: how to pass values in XML

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a simple fragment with 2 TextView objects. The fragment has the corresponding Java class. How do I pass values from the activity layout XML to the fragment? I want to instantiate the same fragment multiple times with the TextView objects having different values.

So, the activity XML would be something like:
    *

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that you are expecting some way of data binding in xml (for example like in wpf). 
There is no data binding like that in android (at least not without third party libraries).

What you do have is your onCreateView () method of fragment. 
There you catch reference to those TextView objects, like this:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container,
                false);
       TextView myTextView1 = (TextView)view.findViewById ("textView1");
       TextView myTextView2 = (TextView)view.findViewById ("textView2");
        return view;
    }
```

There you can also set value of those textViews, or you can set it latter in code like this:

```
myTextView1.setText ("this is my textview1 test");
```

So, to conclude - there is no typical inside xml data binding in android, you have to find those views in fragment code and then manipulate with them.

EDIT:

if you have data somewhere in activity, and you want to pass it to your fragment when you create it, you can use fragment setArgument() function (and corresponding getArguments() ).

You have example here: [Setting Fragment arguments from Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24814389/setting-fragment-arguments-from-activity)  - in the accepted answer.

EDIT 2:

According to new Data Binding Library it's possible to do binding like this:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <data>
       <variable name="user" type="com.example.User"/>
   </data>
   <LinearLayout
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">
       <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="@{user.firstName}"/>
       <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="@{user.lastName}"/>
   </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

link: https://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html

But note that it's still beta release.

Comment: So, would I have to have a myriad of 'if' conditions and say:
if (name.equals("configFragment")) { text1.setText("Config"); text2.setText("Config description); }
if (name.equals("planFragment")) { text1.setText("Plan"); text2.setText("Plan description); }
etc...

Is that what you mean by your answer? Thx

Comment: Can you explain if your question is: 

1.) Is it posible to put data to layout xml and use it in fragment in data binding or config way?   - the answer is no. 

or 

2.) How to pass data between  fragment and containing activity?

Comment: Yeah, the question was 1), so I am quite puzzled it's not possible. I'm just trying to create customized icons on the main screen with a uniform layout, and have different labels on them. It's possible to do this in code, but it simply seems weird that it's not supported. Am I attacking this from the wrong angle perhaps? I just want reusable UI components with some data being injected at instantiation.

Comment: If you came from background where data binding is supported it's very weird. It was very weird to me also, I came from WPF/Silverlight background and I was very surprised it was not supported. From what I know it's not yet supported natively in android, maybe with some third part libraries.

Comment: let me correct my self, after short catch with google...looks like it's possible now with new Data Binding Library 
https://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html

Answer (score 2):

Everybody seems to ignore it but you **can** actually pass static arguments like a label through XML.

It's a bit complicated. First you need to declare the custom attributes you want to use in a file like `attrs.xml`, then you need to override `Fragment.onInflate()` to retrieve the value of these attributes.

The [official Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#onInflate(android.app.Activity,%20android.util.AttributeSet,%20android.os.Bundle)) provides a simple example on how to retrieve a label from the XML layout to use it in a Fragment.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are going about using fragment wrong.

But nonetheless you can just use textview.setText in each fragments java class...

Comment: Not sure why I am going about fragments wrong. Aren't they also supposed to be reusable and dynamic chunks of UI? I simply want a configurable fragment where I can pass values in the activity layout XML. Are you suggesting I use different Java classes (one for each configuration of the TextView contents) for the same fragment layout xml?

Answer (score 0):

you want to pass data to the fragment and let the fragment use it. The following article describes the whole 9 yard:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

In short:
sender to setArguments:

```
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString("myText", aText);
f.setArguments(args);
```

the receiving Fragment to retrieve argument:

```
String text = getArguments().getInt("myText"); // myTextView.setText(...)
```

Comment: Is there any way to set arguments through the layout XML?

Comment: It doesn't make sense. This code is for passing between object from java class. It's not for xml

Comment: In your Activity class, you can retrieve the value hold in the layout widget first, the pass it to the Framgment class.  Yes, Lennon is right: these are Java code to pass object/values using the MVC pattern.  perhaps you are from .NET background thinking about  the data-binding in the xmal file?  I don't think that can be done in Android layout file.

Answer (score 0):

The following is an example of a `Fragment`. Notice the way you interact with the `TextView`. You just have to create as many fragments as you want and put them into an `ArrayList` so that you will be able to get information from all fragments.

```
public class Yourfragment extends Fragment {

    private TextView mTextView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_fragment, container, false);

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        View _view = getView();

        if(_view != null){

            mTextView = (EditText) _view.findViewById(R.id.your_textView);

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question,

you need to have a mainclass extending `Activity` class from which you will instantiate the fragmnet. And you need a fragment class with those two `TextView` objects ad the class variables with a parameterized constructor . So you need to maintain a `Map` which has key as the name of your fragment and textviewvalue1"+"textviewvalue2.  So now while creating an instance of a fragment, you can send the value yiu have in the map as parameters to that fragment constructor.

Like this:

```
public class Yourfragment extends Fragment { 
private TextView mTextView1;
private TextView mTextView2;

public Yourfragment(String txt1,String txt2){
    super();
    this.mTextView1.setText(txt1);
    this.mTextView2.setText(txt2);
}
 @Override public View
  onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{ 
  //ur logic
} 
@Override public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
 //ur logic
 }
 } }
```

And in the place where you instantiate, use `map.get( fragmentname).split("+")[0]` and `map.get( fragmentname).split("+")[1]` as parameters to conatructor and set the title of fragment to fragmentname